# Why is clock() not showing a linear scale with an increase of threads when using printf() from multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, clock

My understanding of `clock()` is that the function returns the number of CPU cycles the program has been scheduled on the CPU since the program has started.

So if I have N threads, and N <= the number of CPU's on my system, and each thread can be scheduled at the same time, then the return of `clock()` will be N times greater in the same given amount of "wall time" than a process with only 1 thread because there are N scheduled threads eating CPU cycles at one time in my 1 process.

This all makes sense, and I've written a program that does this. The output is as follows:

But... If I re-arrange the call to `printf()` and `fflush()`, then the output is very much not what I'd expect...

I've tried to write a minimally reproduce-able version of this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


typedef float real;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int num_threads = 1;

  if (argc >= 2)
    printf("N\tclock\twall\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {

    // global start
    clock_t start_clock = clock();
    double start_wall;


    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
    {   
      // thread-local "now"
      clock_t now_clock;
      double now_wall;

      int id = omp_get_thread_num();

      // one thread sets the start time
      if (id == 0) {
          start_wall = omp_get_wtime();
      }   

      #pragma omp barrier

      while (1) {
        now_clock = clock();
        now_wall = omp_get_wtime();

        if (argc < 2)
        printf("%c %d %.2f %.2f",
            13, 
            num_threads,
            ((real)(now_clock - start_clock) / (real)CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
            ((real)(now_wall - start_wall))
          );  
        if (argc < 2)
        fflush(stdout);

        // each thread will break after 10 wall clock seconds
        if (((real)(now_wall - start_wall)) > 10) 
          break;
      };  

      #pragma omp barrier

      // one thread prints the clock() time from run
      if (id == 0) {
        if (argc >= 2)
        printf("%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\n",  
            13, 
            num_threads,
            ((real)(now_clock - start_clock) / (real)CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
            ((real)(now_wall - start_wall))
          );  
        if (argc < 2)
        fflush(stdout);

        // each thread will break after 10 wall clock seconds
        if (((real)(now_wall - start_wall)) > 10) 
          break;
      };  

      #pragma omp barrier

      // one thread prints the clock() time from run
      if (id == 0) {
        if (argc >= 2)
        printf("%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\n",  
            num_threads,
            ((real)(now_clock - start_clock) / (real)CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
            ((real)(now_wall - start_wall))
          );
      }
    }

    num_threads *= 2;

  }
}
```

Code with makefile: https://github.com/tmsimont/clocktest

makefile:

```
CC = icpc
MPICC = mpiicpc
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -qopenmp -O3 -D USE_MKL -mkl=sequential -Wall -xhost

all: main

main: main.cc
  $(CC) main.cc -o main $(CFLAGS)
clean:
  rm -rf main
```

This will take an argument and produce one of 2 ouptputs...

One, (`if (argc >= 2)`)

Produces my expectation:

```
$ ./main expected
N   clock   wall
1   10.01   10.00
2   20.00   10.00
4   40.02   10.00
8   80.03   10.00
16  160.07  10.00
32  319.52  10.00
```

The return of `clock()` increases linearly within a 10 second wall-clock timeframe.

However, if you omit the argument (see code where `if (argc < 2)`)
the output is different...

In this case, each thread outputs an update in "real time" -- so it's hard to copy/paste the output... but the problem is that right around 10 wall-clock seconds the output is basically this:

```
$ ./main
N   clock   wall
1   5.01    10.00
2   10.00   10.00
4   10.00   10.00
8   10.00   10.00
16  10.00   10.00
32  12.00   10.00
```

So it seems that by calling `printf()` and `fflush()` repeatedly from each thread, I'm losing this linear scaling of the return of `clock()`

Can anyone explain why this is happening? What am I missing?

Also... for reference. My "boiled down example" is basically an attempt to analyze and understand the method used for measuring the performance of word2vec: https://github.com/svn2github/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c#L379

Comment: _"and each thread can be scheduled at the same time"_ Please explain this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean if I have <= N CPU's I can get all N threads running at once. I'm running this on a 32-core machine, so I can be almost certain that all 32 of my threads are running concurrently

Comment: @tmsimont All the threads are trying to use the same resource -- they can't all be running concurrently. They have to wait for access to the serialized resource (the output device) and run one at a time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh of course... Thank you! In the actual word2vec program there's a lot of heavy math and throttled calls to printf(). That probably circumvents this, but I was seeing similar issues when trying to scale word2vec on this machine

Comment: And even if that were true, "can be" != "will be".

Comment: Don't forget that stdout is line buffered (I'm assuming this is on Linux), so there's some shenanigans going on when printf encounters \n (stdout gets 'flushed' at that character). It ensures that when multiple threads call printf their output isn't all jumbled up. For a laugh, try using fprintf(stderr...) instead.